# PHP OpenSSL extension has a package?

Tags: apt, php, openssl

I know that OpenSSL extension is in PHP source, but I can't enable it when I perform `apt-get install php5`. There is not even a `apt-get install php5-openssl`. How I must proceed?

Comment: I know this post is old, just some general info. By default, PHP's packages are distributed with `--with-openssl=[defaultpath]`. It means you only have to install openssl (or any other variant) e.g. `sudo apt-get install openssl`  (also check which version of openssl to install due to [heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com), e.g. `sudo apt-cache policy openssl`. To check wether PHP is enabled with openssl just type `php -m | grep openssl` and `php -i | grep OpenSSL`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think SSL support doesn't depend on an extension, it's already built into Ubuntu's PHP. Try creating a PHP file in your web server with this content:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

then access it in a browser (`http://<server>/<file>.php`). You should see:

[image]

and

[image]

I have only these PHP packages installed: libapache2-mod-php5, php5-cli, php5-common, php5-gd, php5-mcrypt, php5-mysql.

Comment: A personal build was forgotten in my system... Thanks!

Comment: Or call the function in a terminal `php -i | grep -i openssl`

Comment: Quick oneliner to list all modules currently enabled in your PHP binary: `php -i | grep enabled`

Answer (score 28):

**Try**:

```
php -i | grep -i openssl
```

If you have the OpenSSL extension installed, you should see something like this:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

It seems that the OpenSSL extension is installed by default.

**Update**:

If you don't have this extension, you can edit *php.ini* file.

From *php.ini*:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
```

Comment: if not what's the answer?

Comment: @BraianMellor In php.ini try to change `;extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension=php_openssl.dll` or maybe look for answer at https://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=310264.0 
Good luck!

Comment: .dll on Linux? Are you sure?

Comment: @BraianMellor you have right it is not solution for Linux... I updated the content of answer...

Comment: My solution was installing the openssl by apt-get. Best!

Comment: @BraianMellor write the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I installed `OpenSSL 1.1.0f` using

```
# apt-get install openssl

# php -i | grep -i openssl
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Hope it help someone!