# OpenSSL extension not available for PHP8.1 on Ubuntu20.04?

Tags: apt, server, apache2, php

I am running a local website using:

- Contao 4.13 CMS
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Apache2
- PHP 8.1

I've upgraded said website from running on Contao 3.5.40 and PHP 5.6.
The contents of the website are displayed as expected with the exception of some header images which are missing and a broken search bar.

I checked the apache2 error logs to try to find the root of the problem and in it I found:

```
[Fri Jan 05 11:57:04.458185 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 128763] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20210902/open>
PHP Warning:  Module "intl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Jan 05 11:57:04.563161 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 128837] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal ope>
[Fri Jan 05 11:57:04.563230 2024] [core:notice] [pid 128837] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I went to check my PHP extensions directory `/usr/lib/php/20210902/` and found that indeed openssl was not present in the file

I tried `sudo apt-get install php8.1-openssl` but it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-openssl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-openssl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.1-openssl'
```

I've made sure that the `extension=openssl` line is uncommented in my `php.ini` file.

I've also tried to use the PHP source code and the commands

```
./configure --with-openssl
make
sudo make install
```

With no luck. Any ideas on how to get the extension or if the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Old but apparently related: [PHP OpenSSL extension has a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323005/php-openssl-extension-has-a-package)

Comment: I've checked and my php info page states that OpenSSL is enabled, but my apache error logs state that it is still looking for a package in my extensions folder @steeldriver.

Comment: AFAIK you will need to search the ini files, find where you have enabled it as an extension, and remove or comment that out - see for example [PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936034/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-openssl-in-ubuntu)